# Is it right to ask, "Where are you packing your bags to go?"

Tags: sentence-construction, questions

I want to ask the place the person is going when I see him/her packing their bags. 
Should I say:

> "Where are you packing your bags **to go**?"

Or should I say

> "**To go where** are you packing your bags?"

Are both correct or incorrect? Is there are better way to ask it?

Comment: Grammatically, both examples are perfectly valid. But as with *What are you peeling onions to cook?* or *To cook what are you peeling onions?*, these are clumsy constructions that most native speakers would avoid like the plague. It's much more natural to just ask ***Why** are you packing your bags? **What** are you peeling onions for?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That exact wording, “Where are you packing your bags to go?” would be understood by an English speaker, but isn't 'correct'.  If coming from a native speaker, it sounds like they didn't complete the thought before speaking or are taking a short cut.

Taken *literally*, you're asking where the bags are going, implying *without* the owner.

To politely ask where someone is going after seen them packing, you could say:

> I see you're packing bags, where are you going?

or

> Where are you going?  You're packing bags.

or casually

> What are the bags for?  Taking a trip?